# Oracle Case Statement with date value not a valid month

Tags: oracle

I have the below case statement but I would like to add on to the case statement where END_DT is 1/1/3000 classify as Open.

```
CASE WHEN x.END_dt IS NOT NULL OR REASON IS NOT NULL 
THEN 'Closed' ELSE 'Open' END AS Enrolled
```

I'm getting the below results but in this case this should be classified as Open under the Enrolled column

I've tried adding to the Case Statment but I get errors.

One - inconsistent datatype; expected Date got number
Two - When add '1/1/3000' to the date -  Not a valid month.

Help would be appreciated.

Table

```
 id  End_dt          Reason  Enrolled
  1    1/1/3000               Closed
```

Comment: Please show the a complete, valid sql statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mathguy for reminding me about the ANSI standard date format.  I changed my example so assuming x.END_dt is a DATE datatype:

```
  CASE
    WHEN x.END_dt = date '3000-01-01'
      THEN 'Open'
    WHEN x.END_dt IS NULL AND REASON IS NULL
      THEN 'Open'
    WHEN x.END_dt IS NOT NULL OR REASON IS NOT NULL
      THEN 'Closed'
    ELSE 'Unexpected x.END_dt value: ' || to_char(x.END_dt)
  END AS Enrolled
```

I also tightened up the case statement to handle an unexpected END_dt value and explicitly test conditions on their own 'WHEN' lines.  I like to do this as this way the intention of the test is clear, it's clear which expression is being testing when stepping through a debugger (like Toad), and when the clients inevitably want to change things its easy to move a line around or change the order of tests when they are on their own lines.

Comment: Can you explain what 'Unexpected x.END_dt value: ' || to_char(x.END_dt) is doing? Thanks!

Comment: @Toby It returns the message with the END_dt value concatenated onto the end.  Just to show a way of handling an exception.  In reality you would not return this but log or e-mail it or something.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any reliance on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, one can use the ANSI standard date format (which is supported by Oracle): `WHEN x.end_dt = date '3000-01-01' THEN ...`. The whole `CASE` expression can be written like so:

```
CASE
  WHEN x.end_dt = date '3000-01-01' OR (x.end_dt IS NULL AND x.reason IS NULL)
    THEN 'Open'
  ELSE   'Closed'
END AS enrolled
```

Comment: I always forget about the ANSI standard date, thanks for that. I'm going to update my example above.

Comment: When I change to ANSI standard date format I get an error - "Literal does not match format string".  '01-JAN-3000' works fine but why should I use the  ANSI standard date format and how do I fix the error?

Comment: Can you please post the portion of your query where you get the error - EXACTLY as you have it written? The ANSI standard date format does NOT use a format string, but I can't tell what is wrong with your code if I don't see it.